# Qt Cannot Parse Project File

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt-creator, debian-jessie

I started a Qt Creator project on a Debian Jessie system. I have added the project to git. On a different Debian Jessie system, I imported the project on Qt Creator via git cloning. Qt Creator reports

```
Could not find qmake configuration default
Error while parsing file <projectpath>.pro. Giving up.
```

As far as I know, I have installed all of the correct packages. Under the Build & Run options, it has the Desktop kit. It is auto-detecting Qt 4 and Qt 5 (both were installed on the original system), and it is auto-detecting gcc and gdb.

The qmake.conf on both systems for linux-g++ and linux-g++-32 are identical. The files they include are present on both systems.

This seems to be an ongoing problem with Qt. I found Stack Overflow questions on it dating back 2013. Most of those seem to have been related to building Qt from source, though, so they weren't really helpful.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

UPDATE: If I run Qt Creator as root, I can create and open existing projects. Apparently, this is a permissions issue, but I have no idea where to begin looking.

Answer (score 3):

Deleting $HOME/.config/QtCreator*. solved the problem.

I have no idea what caused this. All of the configuration files were owned by me and had read permission.

Answer (score 0):

Done a fresh installation of Linux Mint XFCE 22.1. Installed Qt and Qt Creator. When I tried to make a new project or open an existing one then I got the same:
"Error while parsing file .pro. Giving up."

(Didn't have such a problem on Linux Mint XFCE 22)

Indeed, removing $HOME/.config/QtProject solved the problem.
The folder will be recreated when you open again Qt Creator.